# How to calculate the pulsating current flowing through a shunt resistor?

Tags: shunt, power-dissipation

If the current flowing through the shunt (0.5 ohm) is in pulsating form (PWM with 50% duty cycle and 100 Hz frequency,) how do I calculate power loss through shunt in order to choose proper for application? (Driving a solenoid with pulse and hold approach.)

Maximum peak value is 0.8A while pulse and maximum peak value while hold is 0.5A. See the image below of my current flowing through the shunt.

[image]

If I have to calculate the power loss then what would be the equation I have to take in account? Maybe I can do \$P = I_{RMS}^2 R\$, but I am more interested in how to calculate it by integration and then compare it with \$P = I_{RMS}^2 R\$ for me to learn and understand.

I am sorry in advance if this question is too naïve to answer here. (May be you can give me a link as well if this kind of calculation is done.) I am just trying to understand.

***EDIT:*** 0.8A current staying for 500ms and 0.5A current staying for 12 seconds than again 0.8A current for 500ms repeat it self.

Comment: The power rating for a resistor depends on **temperature**, which depends on **how long** the current is 0.8 A, but you haven't told us anything about absolute time. Unless you can analyze the resistor's temperature as a function of time it would be prudent to assume that the maximum power is continuous.

Comment: APX100, It sounds as though you don't want an answer about how to select a resistor so much as you want an answer that shows you how to compare the results from integration that covers the use of 75% and 50% duty cycles and differing currents vs the use of RMS values. So are you looking more for the math than a practical answer? Or?

Comment: Hi Jonk. Yes, you are right. I am looking for math equation to compare how close is the RMS value (I believe they will be close) to the calculated value.

Comment: It's been a long time, but to integrate that, I think you need the equations of the waveform(s).  You'll probably have to do some piece wise integration and then add them together.

Comment: I will say again that integrating over the two duty factors is not sufficient to determine the power rating of the resistor. The thermal time constant of the system must be considered.

Comment: @APX100 I'll write up something about the math when I get a moment. Thanks for letting me know what's what you are looking to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The average power for a period is the total energy dissipated in that period of time divided by the length of time:

$$\overline{P}=\frac{1}{t_1 - t_0}\int_{t_0}^{t_1} V_t\: I_t\:\:\textrm{d}t$$

Power, as defined above, can be positive or negative. But given a constant load, \$R\$, then either \$V_t=I_t\:R\$ or \$I_t=\frac{V_t}{R}\$ can be applied:

$$\overline{P}=\frac{1}{t_1 - t_0}\frac1R\int_{t_0}^{t_1} V_t^2\:\:\textrm{d}t=\frac{1}{t_1 - t_0}R\int_{t_0}^{t_1} I_t^2\:\:\textrm{d}t$$

And it cannot now be negative (so long as you move forward in time like most of us, anyway.)

\$R\$ can be moved to the other side of the equation so that you either have \$V_{_\textrm{RMS}}^{^{2}}=R\cdot\overline{P}\$ or else \$I_{_\textrm{RMS}}^{^{2}}=\frac{\overline{P}}{R}\phantom{\:}\$.

The resulting equations are then:

$$\begin{align*}
V_{_\textrm{RMS}}&=\sqrt{\frac{1}{t_1 - t_0}\int_{t_0}^{t_1} V_t^2\:\:\textrm{d}t}
\\\\
I_{_\textrm{RMS}}&=\sqrt{\frac{1}{t_1 - t_0}\int_{t_0}^{t_1} I_t^2\:\:\textrm{d}t}
\end{align*}$$

---

The inner integrations, \$\int_{t_0}^{t_1} V_t^2\:\:\textrm{d}t\$ and \$\int_{t_0}^{t_1} I_t^2\:\:\textrm{d}t\$, are *action integrals*. That is, they summarize into a single scalar value the history of some *action* over some period of time. (In physics, the term *action* has an important role enshrined by the *principle of least action*.)

In electronics, action integrals are used to specify ratings for fuses or to help in analyzing datasheets for pulse-rated resistors.

---

In your case, the starting time is \$t_0=0\:\text{s}\$ (because we can "just say it is") and then \$t_1=500\:\text{ms}\$ and \$t_2=12.5\:\text{s}\$, which then covers your total repeating cycle:

$$\begin{align*}
I_{_\textrm{RMS}}&=\sqrt{\frac{1}{t_2 - t_0}\left[\int_{t_0}^{t_1} I_t^2\:\:\textrm{d}t+\int_{t_1}^{t_2} I_t^2\:\:\textrm{d}t\right]}
\\\\
&=\sqrt{\frac{1}{12.5\:\text{s}}\left[\int_{0\:\text{s}}^{500\:\text{ms}}\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\! I_t^2\:\:\textrm{d}t+\int_{500\:\text{ms}}^{12.5\:\text{s}} \!\!\!\!\!\!\!I_t^2\:\:\textrm{d}t\right]}
\end{align*}$$

But you know that in your first phase, there are exactly 50 pulse periods (\$10\:\text{ms}\$ each.) Each pulse period has an 80% duty cycle and so active for only \$8\:\text{ms}\$, being zero for the remaining \$2\:\text{ms}\$. So we know that the total active time is \$8\:\text{ms}\cdot 50=400\:\text{ms}\$. Also, you know that \$I_t=800\:\text{mA}\$. So you can readily compute that the first integral term within the square root is: \$400\:\text{ms}\cdot \left(800\:\text{mA}\right)^2=0.256\:\text{A}^2\:\text{s}\$.

You know that in your second phase, there are exactly 1200 pulse periods (\$10\:\text{ms}\$ each.) Each pulse period has a 50% duty cycle and so active for only \$5\:\text{ms}\$, being zero for the remaining \$5\:\text{ms}\$. So we know that the total active time is \$5\:\text{ms}\cdot 1200=6\:\text{s}\$. Also, you know that \$I_t=500\:\text{mA}\$. So you can readily compute that the second integral term within the square root is: \$6\:\text{s}\cdot \left(500\:\text{mA}\right)^2=1.5\:\text{A}^2\:\text{s}\$.

So the final answer is: \$I_{_\textrm{RMS}}=\sqrt{\frac{1}{12.5\:\text{s}}\left[0.256\:\text{A}^2\:\text{s}+1.5\:\text{A}^2\:\text{s}\right]}\approx 375\:\text{mA}_{_\textrm{RMS}}\$. That's the final figure that includes both the first and second phases. So that's also the result for all integer number of recurring periods, \$N\ge 1\$.

To confirm this through a different approach, you can find that the energy delivered is \$50\cdot 8\:\text{ms}\cdot 500\:\text{m}\Omega\cdot \left(800\:\text{mA}\right)^2+1200\cdot 5\:\text{ms}\cdot 500\:\text{m}\Omega\cdot \left(500\:\text{mA}\right)^2=878\:\text{mJ}\$.

Average power is \$\frac{878\:\text{mJ}}{12.5\:\text{s}}=70.24\:\text{mW}\$. Now compute \$500\:\text{m}\Omega\cdot 375\:\text{mA}_{_\textrm{RMS}}^2\approx 70.31\:\text{mW}\$, the difference due to the fact that I rounded the earlier result to \$375\:\text{mA}_{_\textrm{RMS}}\$.

That's the mathematics part. That's what you asked for. So there it is.

---

The safest way to go, for example when designing the board with a PWM driven by uncertain software, is to assume the worst. In that case, you'd want a resistor rated for at least \$\frac12\:\Omega\cdot \left(800\:\text{mA}\right)^2 =320\:\text{mW}\$. You don't round that down, but up. So at least \$\frac12\:\text{W}\$ if you like keeping your margins slim. Or \$1\:\text{W}\$, if you are more safety-minded.

There are "pulse-rated" resistors. Chip-type resistors rated for pulsing are wider than usual to avoid current crowding. (You know that fuses are designed with very narrow wires inside for exactly the opposite reason -- you want the fuse to fail at certain currents.) Wire-wound resistors are another approach, which also come in nice cemented bodies. A lot of companies make these kinds of resistors and they will (or should) rate them.

Still, you aren't in the "pulse" market. You are operating these resistors over relatively long periods of time with pulses that are *almost continuous*. Anything in the area of 50% to 100% is to be treated as an average. So if you knew that it would be a 50% duty cycle, then you might reasonably say that a \$\frac12\:\text{W}\$ resistor could handle \$1\:\text{W}\$ peak pulses. That's as far as you need to go and there's no need to dwell on action integrals see where a resistor might *fuse*.

This doesn't help your situation much because your early pulses are \$320\:\text{mW}\$. 80% of that just means \$256\:\text{mW}\$, average. That may mean that a \$\frac12\:\text{W}\$ now appears to be a safer choice. But it doesn't mean much more than that.

Comment: Hi Jonk. This is very insightful answer with what I wanted! Thank you so much. One question, as the total power loss is derived around 70.2 mW that means that if I select the shunt rated for 0.1W, that would be enough? or it should be evaluate as @vir answered above?

Comment: Hi Jonk. And second question as well: The picture in post is referred as one cycle. I do have this cycling for 2 minutes (total 12 cycles in 2 minutes). How would this change equation and answer?

Comment: @APX100 vir's approach allows you to just ignore all this "calculation stuff" by rating the resistor for the worst case. (This *could* happen if, for example, your PWM didn't work right and got *stuck*.) If you are absolutely sure that will *never happen* then you will have to dig into datasheets to see what the details are for resistors you choose. Keep in mind the ***action*** in the first half-second. In half a second it is already a sixth of the total action for the next 12 seconds! Put another way, you've got four times the stress in the first half-second than in all the next 12 seconds.

Comment: @APX100 I don't know how you get 12 cycles in 2 minutes! 12.5 seconds times 12 is 2.5 minutes, not 2 minutes. How do you achieve that? (The way to compare the action in each period is like this: (0.256/0.5) / (1.5/12), which is about 4. Some resistors, such as wire-wound, will take this kind of thing well. But again, you still need to find a supplier that actually *rates* their resistor to take pulsed events like this. There are such pulse-rated resistors. But you need to look for them.)

Answer (score 2):

800mA continuous into a 0.5 ohm resistor is 1/3W.  I would just go with a 1W shunt and call it a day.  This will also keep your heating low so depending on your application you can just assume that the resistance is constant.

Edit: some additional manufacturer information on selecting and sizing a shunt resistor.  Some of it is specific to Murata shunts but it gives you a good idea of things you should consider:
https://www.murata.com/-/media/webrenewal/products/power/datasheet/dpm_shunts.pdf